# Github contributions from another device not counted?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-remote

As I started committing to my remote repo through my other laptop, I realized that GitHub doesn't count them as contributions. Even though I have the same username, email and password on both devices, the commits made from the second device seem to be made by an anonymous person (I don't see my profile please pic when I track the contributor).
How do I inform GitHub that it's the same user?

Comment: Have you authenticated with your GitHub credentials?

Comment: What is the output of `git log --format=format:'%h %an <%ae>'`? My guess is that some commits have the wrong name or email.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git config` to locally set your username and e-mail on your other laptop:

```
git config user.email learner@stackoverflow.com
git config user.name 'learner'
```

You can also edit your `~/.gitconfig` file directly and add a couple of sections for your name and email.  After executing the above commands, you should a section looking something like the following:

```
[user]
    name = learner
    email = learner@stackoverflow.com
```